# How can I position and img and text and centre them in html?

Tags: html

I am creating a template for my Ebay Store so I only have the style tag to word with. I've managed the text and img side by side but they stay on the left and I need them in the centre.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Code currently:

```
<div style="text-align: center;" display="flex;" align-items="center">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: 3em; color: black;">
        <b>text</b>
    </h1>
    <img src="url" width="3%;">
   </div>
```

It's not a lot that I need to put together - so I just kept it simple using the style tag.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please add a  minimum reproducible example and please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How is your code structured? You can make a class and use  "display: flex; justify-content: center;".

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap;">
  <div style="flex:1 0 auto; width:48%; margin-right:2%; text-align:right;  background-color:#aa4444; ">
    <h1 style="margin-top:0px">
        This is the title
    </h1>
    This is the description.<br/>
    You only need to remove the background-color property.
  </div>
  <div style="flex:1 0 auto; width:48%; margin-left:2%; background-color:#77aa77;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/180">
  </div>
 </div>
```